# pip3 linked to Python.framework instead of Homebrew /usr/local/bin

Tags: pip, homebrew

I'm using OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

I have just installed Python 3.5 with Homebrew:
`brew install python3`.

`which python3` gives me the location `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

But when I try `which pip3` I get the location `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3`.

How do I link pip3 to work with my Homebrew Python3 install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Python 3.5 install the corresponding `pip` (which should get automatically installed), is `pip3.5`. So you should be able to use it by just that command. (If that doesn't work try `/usr/local/bin/pip3.5` or /usr/local/bin/pip`, but the latter would IMO be an error in the packaging)

In most multi version Python installations you can get the specific minor version of both `python` and `pip` by using `pythonX.Y` resp. `pipX.Y`, with `X` being the major version number and `Y` being the minor version number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I solved the problem by editing `.bash_profile` and adding `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. However since my `etc/paths` already was properly ordered I'm not sure if this really should've been necessary.

Comment: @Winterflags I think that path was already in, otherwise `which python3` would probably not have found `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so you might want to check your path (`echo $PATH`) if `/usr/local/bin` is in there twice. (it cannot hurt, but it is messy IMO if the same path is there twice)